# SQLAlchemy __init__ not running

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = session.query_property()

class CommonBase(object):
  created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
  updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)

class Look(Base, CommonBase):
  __tablename__ = "looks"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

  def __init__(self):
    print "__init__ is run"
    Base.__init__(self)
    self.feedback = None

  def set_feedback(self, feedback):
    """Status can either be 1 for liked, 0 no response, or -1 disliked.
    """
    assert feedback in [1, 0, -1]
    self.feedback = feedback

  def get_feedback(self):
    return self.feedback
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/src/giordano/web/backend.py", line 94, in wrapped
    ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/src/giordano/web/backend.py", line 81, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/src/giordano/web/backend.py", line 187, in next
    json_ret = ge.encode(results)     # automatically pulls the tags
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/src/giordano/__init__.py", line 54, in default
    jsonable = self.convert_to_jsonable(obj)
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/src/giordano/__init__.py", line 40, in convert_to_jsonable
    image_url=obj.image_url, feedback=obj.get_feedback())
  File "/Volumes/Data2/Dropbox/projects/Giordano/src/giordano/models.py", line 100, in get_feedback
    return self.feedback
AttributeError: 'Look' object has no attribute 'feedback'
```

It seems to me that my `__init__` method is not run as I can't see any print statements in my log.

Can someone explain why my `__init__` is not run and what can I do for this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check out the [SQLAlchemy documentation on reconstruction](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html):

> The SQLAlchemy ORM does not call `__init__` when recreating objects from
>   database rows. The ORM’s process is somewhat akin to the Python
>   standard library’s pickle module, invoking the low level `__new__`
>   method and then quietly restoring attributes directly on the instance
>   rather than calling `__init__`.
>
> If you need to do some setup on database-loaded instances before
>   they’re ready to use, you can use the @reconstructor decorator to tag
>   a method as the ORM counterpart to `__init__`. SQLAlchemy will call this
>   method with no arguments every time it loads or reconstructs one of
>   your instances. This is useful for recreating transient properties
>   that are normally assigned in your `__init__`:

```
from sqlalchemy import orm

class MyMappedClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        # we need stuff on all instances, but not in the database.
        self.stuff = []

    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        self.stuff = []
```

> When obj = MyMappedClass() is executed, Python calls the `__init__`
>   method as normal and the data argument is required. When instances are
>   loaded during a Query operation as in query(MyMappedClass).one(),
>   `init_on_load` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I was looking through the docs for "object instantiation" and never thought about the term "reconstruction"!

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if they use that word in the docs, but yeah it seems that the nature of ORMs mean there are many small details like this that aren't immediately obvious. There isn't a standard set of terms that make it easy to know what search terms to use.

Comment: I'm not sure if i like this behaviour or not... It caused some really odd effects in my code. But at least i know it now how the entities are build.